# Excel VBA - selecting range to last completely blank row

Tags: vba, excel

I have some VBA code that needs to select a range from A84 to X. I'm using this code to select that range to the last row in the data.

```
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Range("A84:X" & Lastrow).Select
```

This stops at the first row with a blank cell in the A column. I need it to check columns A through Z, not just A. For example, if there is a value in column A on rows 84 to 94, but for row 95, there's only data in column F or R, it won't include row 95. How can this look at columns A:Z to determine whether or not the row is blank?

Comment: Column **X** or column **Z** ??

Comment: Well, I need to select column X in the range, but I need it to check A:Z in determining whether or not it is blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply set `Lastrow` to

```
Lastrow = Range("A:Z").Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm all but certain there is a better way, but one such way is to loop through you columns and find the last row of each and then determine which one of those is the greatest.

```
maxRow = 0
for i=1 to 24 'A through X
    if maxRow < ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row then
        maxRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
    end if
next i
```

Then `maxRow` is what you want `lastrow` to be.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through all of the columns and compare the last row of each column. You could then change the lastRow variable whenever you find a column with more rows like so:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
lastRow = 1
For i = 1 To 26
    Dim lst As Integer
    lst = Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
    If lst > lastRow Then
        lastRow = lst
    End If
Next
Range("A84:X" & lastRow).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the usedrange function, which returns the complete range of used cells on your sheet:, as follows:

Worksheets("worksheetName").UsedRange.lastRow

This would give you the last *used* row, not just the last row with data in the first column