# copy column to another different layout worksheet

Tags: copy, range

I wish to copy data from Concur into my destination worksheet - Upload to Sun:

- From Concur column J into UploadtoSun column D
- From Concur column P into UploadtoSun column J
  etc etc

My error message was the last sentence - Application defined or object defined error.

I'm not too sure how to write the last sentence. Can anyone assist ?

```
Dim ConcurLastRow As Long
Set Concur = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Concur")
Set UploadtoSun = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("UploadtoSun")
Dim ConcurRngF As Range
Dim ConcurRngJ As Range
Dim ConcurRngK As Range
Dim ConcurRngO As Range
Dim ConcurRngP As Range

Dim UploadtoSunRngD As Range
Dim UploadtoSunRngF As Range
Dim UploadtoSunRngJ As Range
Dim UploadtoSunRngK As Range
Dim UploadtoSunRngL As Range

ConcurLastRow = Concur.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
UploadtoSunLastRow = Worksheets("UploadtoSun").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Set ConcurRngF = Concur.Range("F11:G" & ConcurLastRow)
Set ConcurRngJ = Concur.Range("J11:K" & ConcurLastRow)
Set ConcurRngK = Concur.Range("K11:L" & ConcurLastRow)
Set ConcurRngO = Concur.Range("O11:P" & ConcurLastRow)
Set ConcurRngP = Concur.Range("P11:Q" & ConcurLastRow)

Set UploadtoSunRngD = UploadtoSun.Range("D2:E" & UploadtoSunLastRow)
Set UploadtoSunRngF = UploadtoSun.Range("F2:G" & UploadtoSunLastRow)
Set UploadtoSunRngJ = UploadtoSun.Range("J2:K" & UploadtoSunLastRow)
Set UploadtoSunRngK = UploadtoSun.Range("K2:L" & UploadtoSunLastRow)
Set UploadtoSunRngL = UploadtoSun.Range("L2:M" & UploadtoSunLastRow)

Worksheets("UploadtoSun").Range("UploadtoSunRngD").Copy Worksheets("Concur").Range("ConcurRngJ").Value
```

Comment: *My error message was the last sentence - Application defined or object defined error.* In what line? And show full procedure code (and global definitions if exists), not partial one.

Comment: The problem source may be that `Rows.Count` is referenced not to application/worksheet/range but somewhere else. Specify its `Parent.`.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this

```
 Sub Copydata()

 Dim lastRow As Long
  lastRow = Worksheets("Concur").Range("J:Z").Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

  'copy range
  Worksheets("Concur").Range("J1:" & "J" & lastRow).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("UploadtoSun").Range("D1")

  'copy entire column
   Worksheets("Concur").Range("J:J").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("UploadtoSun").Range("K:K")

  End Sub
```

how to get the last row [Excel VBA - selecting range to last completely blank row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39882196/excel-vba-selecting-range-to-last-completely-blank-row)

Comment: if i would like to edit the code into the following, but would like to go for PasteValue. How should i do ?                                                           
    Worksheets("Concur").Cells(i, 16).Copy
    Worksheets("Concur").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("UploadtoSun").Cells(UploadtoSunLastRow, 10)

Comment: `Worksheets("Concur").Columns("J").Copy
   Worksheets("UploadtoSun").Columns("K").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
   
   Worksheets("Concur").Range("J1:" & "J" & lastRow).Copy
   Worksheets("UploadtoSun").Range("L1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`     copy and paste must be on separate lines